# Binary decision diagram for a six-figure Boolean function

Tags: formal-methods

> Let $p$ be the six-figure Boolean function with the following definition:
>
> $p(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4},x_{5})=\begin{cases}
>   true & \text{if } x_{0}=x_{5} \text{ and } x_{1}=x_{4} \text{ and } x_{2}=x_{3}, \\
>   false & \text{else.}
> \end{cases}$
>
> This function obviously yields $true$ iff $x_{0}x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}x_{5}$ is a palindrome. Provide a BDD for $p$ relative to a variable ordering of your choice.

My problems begin when I try to define an appropriate variable ordering, so I am only able to guess it: $x_{0}=x_{5} < x_{1}=x_{4} < x_{2}=x_{3}$.
I'm actually pretty lost with this exercise and any help is much appreciated (sorry for not being able to provide a better own approach).

Comment: In you answer you test whether all variables are true. Instead you should test $x_0=x_5$ etc. The order of variables seems sensible to me.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thank you, Hendrik. Can you check my updated solution, please?

Comment: Seems OK to me: the BSD closely follows the description of the formula.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thank you for the quick respone and for your help. Can you have also a look into my other thread "Logical conjunction of two binary decision diagrams", please (certainly only if you have the time and motivation left)? Obviously nobody is interested in it and I've been even voted down twice...

Comment: PS. Donald Knoth in his Volume 4 TAoCP on BDD's says it is sometimes convenient to allow repetitions of the T and F leaves "to avoid excessively long connecting lines". I do not whether you are allowed to have two F-nodes at the bottom, but it would remove some of the clutter.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks for this hint. I've checked our definition of a BDD and it does not provide any information on this. I'll better let my solution unchanged and ask them if repetitions are allowed.

Comment: There is two spurious lines going out of x0. (BTW, you are allowed to anwer your question, I wonder if it wouldn't be better to do so and remove the answer from the question).

Comment: @AProgrammer: Thank you very much. This exercise is the best example for "to miss the forest for the trees". I've answered my question and hope that this third attempt will be also the last one.

Comment: For posterity, to check your solution, you could learn to use one of the existing [BDD software packages](https://github.com/johnyf/tool_lists/blob/master/bdd.md), which is a also a good exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally this should be the correct solution:

The variable ordering is $x_{0} < x_{5} < x_{1} < x_{4} < x_{2} < x_{3}$. The BDD is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#Variable_ordering) article has a fairly good example in the "Variable Ordering" section. By carefully picking the order we evaluate the variables in, we can come to (at least some) decisions sooner.

In your case, if we know that for example $x_{0} = true$ and $x_{5}=false$, we can immediately answer $false$, regardless of the values of the other variables. You should be able to extend this to a full BDD of reasonably small size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Luke. I've edited my question and it would be nice, if you could check it. BTW: Any help in my other BDD-related question would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: @Uriel, that looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you for some assistance with my other BDD-related [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/logical-conjunction-of-two-binary-decision-diagrams)? I am sure only a few words would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what you've tried so far?  The problem says you can choose any variable ordering you want, so I'm a bit puzzled why you are trying to choose an "appropriate" variable ordering or guess a variable ordering. I suggest you choose any variable ordering you want (anything, really, it doesn't matter what you choose, just pick one), and then try to build the BDD.  Why don't you try that, and then show us what you got?  At that point we might be able to help you better.

P.S. When we say a variable ordering, we mean an ordering: a list of the variables in some order.  An example of a variable ordering would be $x_0,x_5,x_1,x_4,x_2,x_3$.  (I'm not sure what's going on with $x_0=x_5$; that's not a valid part of a variable ordering.)

Comment: I've now provided a solution in my question. Please check if it is correct. Could you also have a look into my other BDD-related thread, please? Thank you.